# Unable to execute jar file through jenkins with sauceLabs

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have created jar file for my maven selenium webdriver project through POM.xml. which is checkout from SVN repository. The two jar files were created in target folder.But when I try to execute this jar it says... Could not find or load main class com.sample.MainTestClass

Below is the code and I used the command mvn package in "Execute windows batch file" in jenkins

```
    <plugin>  
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>  
     <configuration>  
       <archive>  
         <manifest>  
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
           <mainClass>com.sample.MainTestClass</mainClass>  
         </manifest>      
       </archive>  
       <descriptorRefs>  
         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>  
       </descriptorRefs>  
     </configuration>  
     <executions>  
       <execution>  
         <id>make-assembly</id>  
         <phase>package</phase>  
         <goals>  
           <goal>single</goal>  
         </goals>  
       </execution>  
     </executions>  
   </plugin>
```

Following is the structure of resultant jar from the command 
"jar tf CPTK-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

META-INF/

META-INF/maven/

META-INF/maven/com.saucelabs/

META-INF/maven/com.saucelabs/CPTK/

META-INF/maven/com.saucelabs/CPTK/pom.properties

META-INF/maven/com.saucelabs/CPTK/pom.xml

Is there anything I need to add in this pom.xml file?
Please help to solve this problem
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the structure of your resultant jar to your question body (by using `jar tf yourJar.jar`)?

Comment: Change the goal to java instead of single and try once...

Comment: where is MainTestClass located? under src/main or src/test?

Comment: MainTestClass was located in src/test/java. Even I tried it by placing that MainTestClass in src/main also.

Comment: Structure of resultant jar---
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.saucelabs/
META-INF/maven/com.saucelabs/CPTK/
META-INF/maven/com.saucelabs/CPTK/pom.properties
META-INF/maven/com.saucelabs/CPTK/pom.xml

Comment: Akbar,  
when i changed goal to java. It throws following error

"Could not find goal 'java' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 among available goals directory, assembly, directory-single, attached, single, help, unpack, directory-inline"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven Shade plugin for generating executable jar.

< build>

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    < groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>Your Main class</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Please refer this url.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html

Comment: Although the comment from zx485 is the standard StackOverflow one, this is the main page for Apache Maven's shade plugin. If that page changes, it's because Apache has ceased to exist and we have much more to worry about.

Comment: I tried the above code.But it is also not working. Shows the same error. In my question I Showed the structure of resultant jar. Is it creating correctly or not?